# Forwarding MotionEvent from onTouchEvent to a ViewPager

Tags: android

I have a overlay view where I sometimes want to delegates its onTouchEvent's to the underlaying (not a child view) ViewPager, so I do this if that is the case:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        clampedLeftEvent = ev;
    }
    if (!clampedLeftX) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } else if(viewPager != null && clampedLeftX && !isLandscape()) {
        if(clampedLeftEvent != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SKN-onTouchEvent: Sending down action!");
            boolean res = viewPager.onTouchEvent(clampedLeftEvent);
            clampedLeftEvent = null;
            return res;
        }
        return viewPager.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

This is actually working fine in most cases, but sometimes i get the following error in the ViewPager.onTouchEvent:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
            at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
            at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:1983)
            at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.getX(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)
            at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat$EclairMotionEventVersionImpl.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:91)
            at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:219)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1971)

I log all MotionEvent action types in my ViewPager like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    LogUtil.logAction(TAG, event);
    try {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SKN-onTouchEvent", e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I just handle this exception and ignore it, then I loose the touch event and my ViewPager is not dragged/scrolled. One thing I have noticed is that when I do get the exception, my ViewPager never get a ACTION_DOWN event, even though I know I am sending the ACTION_DOWN from my other view (I know I do, I store it in a temp variable and send it and even log out that I am sending it). This happens every second time I drag my finger over the overlay view, the first time I drag I do get the ACTION_DOWN event and everything works, but every second time I do the drag my ViewPager does not get the ACTION_DOWN. It is like the ViewPager filters that ACTION_DOWN event out even before its onTouchEvent is called...?

Any ideas on what I can do here?

Thank you

Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I was on the right path, you need to make sure the ACTION_DOWN event is sent as the first event to the ViewPager, and that was why I was saving it in a local variable, but the problem is that the system is reusing those events so my saved instance was changed and thus it was no longer a ACTION_DOWN. I fixed it by changing

```
clampedLeftEvent = ev;
```

to

```
clampedLeftEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
```